# Azure / Powershell / Get VM IPs with subscription names

Tags: azure, powershell

I have a script that outputs all of my subscription's VM IPs.  The problem I want to solve is getting the subscription name in the output.  Currently, the script goes through all subscriptions and returns VM Name, resource group, internal/external IPs, etc.  But no matter what I try, I can't get the output to also return the subscription name. I can get the field to populate with the subscription heading, but the fields are blank.

My ultimate goal is to get all VMs with public addresses use to audit NSG rules, but include subscription names as well.

Any ideas?

```
$reportName = "AzVMIPs.csv"
Get-AzSubscription | Select-AzSubscription | ForEach-Object {$_ 
$report = @()
$vms = Get-AzVM
$publicIps = Get-AzPublicIpAddress 
$nics = Get-AzNetworkInterface | ?{ $_.VirtualMachine -NE $null}
foreach ($nic in $nics) { 
    $info = "" | Select-Object VmName, ResourceGroupName, Region, VirturalNetwork, Subnet, PrivateIpAddress, OsType, PublicIPAddress 
    $vm = $vms | ? -Property Id -eq $nic.VirtualMachine.id 
    foreach($publicIp in $publicIps) { 
        if($nic.IpConfigurations.id -eq $publicIp.ipconfiguration.Id) {
            $info.PublicIPAddress = $publicIp.ipaddress
            } 
        } 
        $info.OsType = $vm.StorageProfile.OsDisk.OsType 
        $info.VMName = $vm.Name 
        $info.ResourceGroupName = $vm.ResourceGroupName 
        $info.Region = $vm.Location 
        $info.VirturalNetwork = $nic.IpConfigurations.subnet.Id.Split("/")[-3] 
        $info.Subnet = $nic.IpConfigurations.subnet.Id.Split("/")[-1] 
        $info.PrivateIpAddress = $nic.IpConfigurations.PrivateIpAddress 
        $report+=$info 
    } 
$report | Export-CSV "$home\$reportName" -NoTypeInformation -Append
}
```

Thanks,

Answer (score 2):

If you want to  get subscription Name in your report, please refer to the following script

```
$reportName = "AzVMIPs.csv"
(Get-AzSubscription)|ForEach-Object{
 
 Select-AzSubscription $_

$report = @()
$vms = Get-AzVM
$publicIps = Get-AzPublicIpAddress 
$nics = Get-AzNetworkInterface | ?{ $_.VirtualMachine -NE $null}
foreach ($nic in $nics) { 
    $info = "" | Select-Object VmName, ResourceGroupName, Region, VirturalNetwork, Subnet, PrivateIpAddress, OsType, PublicIPAddress, SubscriptionName
    $vm = $vms | ? -Property Id -eq $nic.VirtualMachine.id 
    foreach($publicIp in $publicIps) { 
        if($nic.IpConfigurations.id -eq $publicIp.ipconfiguration.Id) {
            $info.PublicIPAddress = $publicIp.ipaddress
            } 
        } 
        $info.OsType = $vm.StorageProfile.OsDisk.OsType 
        $info.VMName = $vm.Name 
        $info.ResourceGroupName = $vm.ResourceGroupName 
        $info.Region = $vm.Location 
        $info.VirturalNetwork = $nic.IpConfigurations.subnet.Id.Split("/")[-3] 
        $info.Subnet = $nic.IpConfigurations.subnet.Id.Split("/")[-1] 
        $info.PrivateIpAddress = $nic.IpConfigurations.PrivateIpAddress
        $info.SubscriptionName=$_.Name 
        $report+=$info 
    } 
$report | Export-CSV "$home\$reportName" -NoTypeInformation -Append

}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you! This is clean and works great.  Follow up question - how can I sort the columns in excel to output with sub name first, resource group, then VM etc?  It seems changing the order of the $info in the script doesn't affect the output.

Comment: @LæntsM. Please try to change `info=""|...` as `$info = "" | Select-Object SubscriptionName,ResourceGroupName,VmName, Region, VirturalNetwork, Subnet, PrivateIpAddress, OsType, PublicIPAddress`. Besides, please note that delete the original csv file before you try. Because you add `-Append` in command `Export-CSV`

Answer (score 1):

I modified the code a bit and it reports Subscription name also. Please try it yourself

```
$reportName = "D:\AzVMIPs.csv"
Get-AzSubscription | Select-AzSubscription | ForEach-Object {$_ 
$report = @()

$vms = Get-AzVM
$publicIps = Get-AzPublicIpAddress 
$nics = Get-AzNetworkInterface | ?{ $_.VirtualMachine -NE $null}
foreach ($nic in $nics) { 
    $info = "" | Select-Object VmName, ResourceGroupName, Region, VirturalNetwork, Subnet, PrivateIpAddress, OsType, PublicIPAddress, SubscriptionName 
    $vm = $vms | ? -Property Id -eq $nic.VirtualMachine.id 
    foreach($publicIp in $publicIps) { 
        if($nic.IpConfigurations.id -eq $publicIp.ipconfiguration.Id) {
            $info.PublicIPAddress = $publicIp.ipaddress
            } 
        } 
        $info.OsType = $vm.StorageProfile.OsDisk.OsType 
        $info.VMName = $vm.Name
        $info.ResourceGroupName = $vm.ResourceGroupName 
        $info.Region = $vm.Location 
        $info.VirturalNetwork = $nic.IpConfigurations.subnet.Id.Split("/")[-3] 
        $info.Subnet = $nic.IpConfigurations.subnet.Id.Split("/")[-1] 
        $info.PrivateIpAddress = $nic.IpConfigurations.PrivateIpAddress
        $info.SubscriptionName = (Get-AzContext).Name
        $report+=$info
        } 
        
$report | Export-CSV "D:\1.CSV" -NoTypeInformation -Append
}
```

Thanks,
Manu

Comment: Thank you for this!  This worked beautifully!  I chose the other answer only because the subscription name was cleaner in the output and didn't include the sub ID or my company username.

Answer (score 0):

Azure Resource Graph (ARG) can be used as well. Its main advantage is that it will output all the VMs across all subscriptions within a tenant, quite fast. Eg for several thousand VMs across hundreds of subscriptions, it takes **a matter of seconds** to have the output file.

The script further down will report correctly on multiple vmNics and multiple IP configurations per vmNic. If running from either a local Powershell session or Cloud Shell, make sure you have the `Az.ResourceGraph` module installed first.

A sample report ran against my test tenant:

[image]

The script will only report the first 5,000 VMs in the tenant in its current form. For a version that doesn't have such limitations, including being able to report across more than 1,000 Azure subscriptions, the script [here](https://mihai-albert.com/2020/10/01/get-the-list-of-all-azure-vms-with-all-their-private-and-public-ips/#get-the-list-of-all-azure-vms-powershell) can be used, by just swapping out the ARG query with the one seen below.

As for building a very similar Azure Resource Graph query like the one used in the script - which might look cryptic at first - this is described at length [here](https://mihai-albert.com/2020/10/01/get-the-list-of-all-azure-vms-with-all-their-private-and-public-ips/#ARM).

```
$reportName = "AzVMIPs.csv"
$ARG_query = @"
resourcecontainers
    | where type =~ 'microsoft.resources/subscriptions'
    | project id, subscriptionId, subscriptionName = name
    | join (Resources
        | where type =~ 'microsoft.compute/virtualmachines'
        | project vmId = tolower(tostring(id)), vmName = name, subscriptionId
        | join (Resources
            | where type =~ 'microsoft.network/networkinterfaces'
            | mv-expand ipconfig=properties.ipConfigurations
            | project vmId = tolower(tostring(properties.virtualMachine.id)), privateIp = ipconfig.properties.privateIPAddress, publicIpId = tostring(ipconfig.properties.publicIPAddress.id)
            | join kind=leftouter (Resources
                | where type =~ 'microsoft.network/publicipaddresses'
                | project publicIpId = id, publicIp = properties.ipAddress
            ) on publicIpId
            | project-away publicIpId, publicIpId1
            | summarize privateIps = make_list(privateIp), publicIps = make_list(publicIp) by vmId
        ) on vmId
        | project-away vmId1
        | sort by vmName asc
    ) on subscriptionId
    | project-away subscriptionId1
"@
$results = Search-AzGraph -Query $ARG_query -First 5000
$results | Select-Object -ExcludeProperty ResourceId | Export-CSV "$home\$reportName" -NoTypeInformation
```